# Multi-element jQuery animation issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, loops, jquery-animate

I am trying to loop through an animation selecting multiple elements and moving them as long as the mouse hovers over the parent area.  This works well enough, but each time the animation loops through the first element (child) moves faster than the others. ??? [JSFiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/Mitch2017/wotfLyuo/)

HTML:

```
<div id="menuContent">
    <button id="btn1" class="mainButton" left="0"/>
    <button id="btn2" class="mainButton" left="0"/>
    <button id="btn3" class="mainButton" left="0"/>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$("#menuContent").hover(function () {
    loop();
    }
    , function () {
        stop();
    }
);

function stop() {
    $(".mainButton").stop();
}

    function loop() {
   $(".mainButton").stop().animate({ left: "+=20"}, 100, 'linear', function () { loop(); });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the documentation:

> **complete**
>
> A function to call once the animation is complete, called once per matched element.

When you call `animate` it starts 3 animations. Animation for the first element gets started and finished first. And then its `complete` gets called and you stop and start all animations, though some of them didn't get completed yet.

Consider this example ([Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wotfLyuo/3/)):

```
function loop() {
  $('.mainButton').stop().animate({
    left: '+=1'
  }, 1, 'linear', function() {
    loop();
  });
}
```

Only one circle will be moving because there is no time gap for others to move.

You can use promises to make it work ([Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wotfLyuo/6/)):

```
$('#menuContent').hover(function() {
  $('.mainButton').data('run', true);
  loop();
}, function() {
  $('.mainButton').data('run', false);
});

function loop() {
  if (!$('.mainButton').data('run')) return;
  $('.mainButton').animate({left: '+=10'}, 100, 'linear').promise().done(loop);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This is the behavior I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

[Danil Speransky](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1550807/danil-speransky) is correct. However there is an options argument to the animate function to allow animations to not run in a rigid queue.

```
`$(".mainButton").animate({ left: "+=20"},{queue: false}, 100, 'linear', function () { loop();});`
```

Check out the documentation for queue:false [here](http://api.jquery.com/animate/).

Answer (score 0):

You're mileage may vary, but doing these two things seem to help a lot:

First, store the jQuery object for the `.mainButton` elements:

```
var $mainButton = $('.mainButton')
```

Second, Make the `left` increment more and also increase the delay:

```
$mainButton.stop().animate(
  { left: "+=1000"},
  5000,
  'linear', 
  function() { loop() })
```

You can toy with the numbers more to see if you get even better performance.

https://jsfiddle.net/wotfLyuo/8/

Answer (score -1):

Your complete handler is called, if the animation for one elements in the jquery collection is finished. So when the first element is finished, you call loop and stop the animation of the other elements. Better use promise and done and save the state of your animation within the collection:

```
$("#menuContent").hover(function () {
    start();
}, function () {
    stop();
});

function start() {
    $(".mainButton").data('stopped', false);
    loop();
}

function stop() {
    $(".mainButton").data('stopped', true).stop();
}

function loop() {
    var $mainButtons = $(".mainButton").stop();
    if(!$mainButtons.data('stopped'))
        $mainButtons.animate({ left: "+=20"}, 100, 'linear').promise().done(loop);
}
```

Here is a working fiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/wotfLyuo/5/)

Comment: Downvoting without a comment? Please feel free to leave a comment with the reason for downvoting this answer.